# Permission denied on apache2.conf (ubuntu, new linux user here)

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, permissions

I am new to Linux and Apache and have beginners permissions issues ...

I installed Ubuntu and has installed and configured apache and PHP via SSH (putty) from my windows box. apt-get

I have installed WinSCP and has used that for file transfers from Windows to Ubuntu. That is working fine after i figured out how to the permissions on the website directory.

Now I have new permission problems when I try to edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

No matter what i try i get a permission denied.

I am trying to download the file using WinSCP, edit it windows and then upload the file again. This results in a

Permission denied.
Error code: 3
Error message from server: Permission denied

This is my current permissions:

drwxrwxr-x  8 root root    4096 Nov 16 16:24 apache2
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  7115 Jul 21 19:56 apache2.conf

Can anyone point me in to direction?

Answer (score 0):

1) try to SCP as root user
2) try to login as root with SSH and use mcedit to edit the file
please note: in some systems, ssh to root user is prohibited by default, so you have to ssh to your user, and give the command: `su` (and enter the password) or `sudo su` if you have sudo rights.
to access via ssh, use [PUTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).
once you're in, install mc: `apt-get install mc`
after this, you can use mcedit: `mcedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

mcedit is a really well designed editor, it's quite easy to use.

Comment: Doesn't seem to support copy / paste from windows (

Comment: if you want to copy out something, you can view the file with the less command.
you can paste content to the mcedit, but as it is using mouse like you were using that computer, so you can click and select, obviously you can not use this to copy out something. but you can check putty, as somehow you can get the content of the screen, that's for sure ...